# Remove show more options entry in Windows 11 context menu

Tags: windows

I do not like this new change in **Windows 11**. When I click on the `show more options` **context menu** entry, it expands and displays other options in sliding-down animation. How can it be disabled? If not by toggling some settings - then programmatically?

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1 - Modifying registry**

Classic (Old) Context menu

```
@echo off
reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32" /f
EXIT
```

Default Windows 11 Context menu

```
@echo off
reg.exe delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}" /f
EXIT
```

**NOTE:** Run cmd with administrator privileges and then restart file explorer

**Method 2 - One click solution**

[Windows 11 Classic Context Menu v1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlgzG.png)

With the help of the new portable freeware "**Windows 11 Classic Context Menu v1.0**" you can toggle between Classic (Old) Context menu and default Windows 11 Right click menu easily (Just one click)

[Homepage](https://www.sordum.org/14479/windows-11-classic-context-menu-v1-0/)

Answer (score 4):

As a work-around you can press `Shift + Right Click` or `Shift + F10` you'll get an 'old'-style menu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one way you can disable the show more options entry from the windows 11 context menu.

1. Launch the file explorer
2. Go to the menu
3. Choose an option from drop-down list
4. Switch to the view tab
5. Go to the advance settings section
6. Scroll down to launch folder windows in a separate process
7. check the box next to it. Click on okay and restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Create a (**.reg**) file with the following content and double click then restart.

***1.*** "Show More Options" Context Menu **Disable**

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32]
> @=""

***2.*** "Show More Options" Context Menu **Enable**

> [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}]

Comment: Please don't add random .rar download files to answers..

Comment: @Jeppe this is the file of the second solution, just attached for user ease. I already use this solution on my pc

Comment: If everyone started distributing files like this, StackOverflow would be full of viruses eventually.

Comment: Since this platform is for helping people, I have not seen any link policies there. Additionally, seniors have the option of revising the answer. I removed the attachment.